# Center align the viewport

Tags: sencha-touch-2, viewport

I have created an app which launches a viewport on launch. This covers the entire screen. So i provided a width and height for it. The next requirement being the app being center aligned in the screen.

The code I have used is:

```
//<debug>
 Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching:false});
 Ext.Loader.setPath({
'Ext': 'sdk/src'
});
//</debug>

Ext.application({
name: 'SEPA',
controllers: ["MainController"],
requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

controllers:['MainController'],

icon: {
    57: 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    72: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    114: 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    144: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

phoneStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen.jpg',
tabletStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen~ipad.jpg',
fullscreen: false,
//centered:true,
 // margin: 100,

launch: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.setWidth(320);
    Ext.Viewport.setHeight(480);

    //Ext.Viewport.setCentered(false);
   // Ext.Viewport.setRight(2);

    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element

},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    );
}
 });
```

As you can see, the app is placed in the left most corner of the browser. How can i get it in the center of the screen?

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `css` or `scss` file:

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    margin-top:-240px;
}
```

Hope it helps :)